# Filter out unselected fields from table via Many to Many relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

In my project, User can select only one exam at the time of registration. But after logging into the site, user can add another exam. Now the problem is if user selected one perticular exam at the time of registration, he can not add that same exam again. In other words I want to show only unselected exam to that user which is not added by him/her. As I implemented many-to-many relationship in User model.

**1) User.php**

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $primaryKey = 'uid';

    public function exams()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(exam::class, 'exam_user', 'user_id', 'exam_id')->withTimeStamps();
    }
}
```

**2) UsersController.php**

```
class UsersController extends Controller
{
    
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(['auth','verified']);
    }

    public function fetchExams()
    {
        $users = Auth::user();
        $exams_model = exam::all();
        return view('user.myExam', compact('users', 'exams_model'));
    }
}
```

**3) myExam.blade.php**

- In this view user can see which exam is selcted by him/her in one table but I want
  to show user that exams which is not perticularly selected by that user.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>Your Exams</h2>
            @foreach ($users->exams as $exam)
                <p><kbd style="background-color: green; font-size: 16px;">{{$exam->exam_name}}</kbd></p>
            @endforeach
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form action="/addExam" method="POST">
                @csrf
                <h2>Add new exam</h2>
                @foreach ($exams_model as $ex)
                    <p><input type="checkbox" name="{{$ex->eid}}"> <kbd style="background-color: lightblue; color: black; font-size: 16px;">{{$ex->exam_name}}</kbd></p>
                @endforeach
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

**4) Users Table**

```
class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('uid');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('phone')->unique();
            $table->boolean('status')->default(0);
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('profile_image')->default('default.jpg');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

**5) Exams Table**

```
class CreateExamsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('exams', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('eid');
            $table->string('exam_name')->unique();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('exams');
    }
}
```

**6) exam_user Table**

- This table stores user_id and exam_id as foreign key.

```
class CreateUserExamsPivotTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('exam_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('exam_id');
            $table->foreign('exam_id')->references('eid')->on('exams');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('uid')->on('users');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('exam_user');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From My understanding, your need is only to display contents from `exams` not having references to the table `exam_user` with `user_id!=(Logged in user)`

Simple SQL Query maybe like this

`select distinct e.* from exams as e  join exam_user as eu on eu.exam_id = e.eid where eu.user_id = Auth::user()->uid;`

Non eloquent way for Laravel

`$exams = DB::table('exams as e')->left join('exam_user as eu','eu.exam_id','e.eid')->where('eu.user_id','!=',Auth::user()->uid)->get();`

Eloquent Way

`You can get from above non eloquent way. I'm not sure. But above code will work (not tested)`

Comment: It only shows the exams of other user. Ex. - If John has exam named UPSC and Mark has exam named GATE. From your code, John can add only GATE exam which is selected by Mark and Mark can add only UPSC exam which is selected by John. But the question is John can add any exam except UPSC and Mark can add any exam except GATE.